# What is the difference between sup P{|x(t)|>a}=0 and P{sup |x(t)|>a}=0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider that $x(t)$ is a stochastic process, which is a solution of a stochastic differential equation issuing from $x_0$. I want to study the stochastic stability of the zero equilibrium. Two definitions are found in the literature

Weak stochastic stability

$\lim_{x_0 \to 0}\sup P\{|x(t)| \geq a \}=0$

and

Stochastic stability

$\lim_{x_0 \to 0} P\{\sup |x(t)| \geq a \}=0$.

I do not understand the difference between the two definitions. Why the first definition is weaker?

Comment: This doesn't elicit a good answer beyond just re-stating the definition of each, i.e. "one is X and the other is Y". What do you really want to know?

Comment: Sorry for that.I've edited the question. Please take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align} & & \sup_{t}|X(t)| &\geq X(t) \\
&\Rightarrow & \left\{\sup_{t}|X(t)| \geq a\right\} &\supseteq 
\left\{|X(t)| \geq a\right\} \\
&\Rightarrow & \Pr\left\{\sup_{t}|X(t)| \geq a\right\} &\geq
\Pr\left\{|X(t)| \geq a\right\} \\
&\Rightarrow & \Pr\left\{\sup_{t}|X(t)| \geq a\right\} &\geq
\sup_{t}\Pr\left\{|X(t)| \geq a\right\} \\
\end{align}$$
the last line follows from the fact that LHS is independent of $t$ since the first line. So by squeezing principle, if 
$$ \lim_{x_0 \to 0}\Pr\left\{\sup_{t}|X(t)| \geq a\right\} = 0$$
then it implies
$$ \lim_{x_0 \to 0}\sup_{t}\Pr\left\{|X(t)| \geq a\right\} = 0 $$ 
but not the converse. So the first one is a weaker definition.